# Error while scanning a project with Sonar Scanner

Tags: java, sonarqube, maven-3, sonarqube-scan

I have been trying to scan a java project (ArgoUML) with the sonar scanner and I'm getting the following error when using `sonar-scanner` in the project directory:

```
ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
ERROR: Please provide compiled classes of your project with sonar.java.binaries property
```

The project is cloned from this repo:
https://github.com/cscorley/argouml-mirror

I tried building with maven using `mvn package` and `mvn install` but every time I'm getting an error. The last error that I got is:

```
Results :

Failed tests: 

Tests in error: 

Tests run: 1106, Failures: 2, Errors: 8, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] argouml-core 0.35.2-SNAPSHOT ....................... SUCCESS [  0.898 s]
[INFO] argouml-core-model ................................. SUCCESS [  0.783 s]
[INFO] argouml-core-model-mdr ............................. SUCCESS [  8.167 s]
[INFO] argouml-core-model-euml ............................ SUCCESS [  0.162 s]
[INFO] argouml-app ........................................ FAILURE [04:55 min]
[INFO] argouml-core-notation .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] argouml-core-transformer ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] argouml-core-umlpropertypanels ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] argouml-core-diagrams-activity2 .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] argouml-core-diagrams-class2 ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] argouml-core-diagrams-sequence2 .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] argouml-core-diagrams-state2 ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] argouml-core-diagrams-structure2 0.35.2-SNAPSHOT ... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 05:05 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-05-03T12:07:31+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.8.1:test (default-test) on project argouml: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to /Users/redhood148/Documents/git/argouml-mirror/src/argouml-app/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
```

Any suggestions how I can fix this?
Let me know if you need more info.

Thanks.

Comment: What's in the mentioned surefire-reports? Sonarqube needs the test to pass (or at least, not to fail the build).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not exactly know the reason for this, but can help you with the solution that worked for me.

You must have mentioned the source path under "sonar.sources" in your configuration specifying the source package from where code needs to be scanned.
eg. `sonar.sources=/home/workspace/codecoveragejob/Test_project/Test_project_service/src`

along with this property, set another property under "sonar.java.binaries" and provide same value as "sonar.sources".

So it would look something like this:

```
sonar.sources=/home/workspace/codecoveragejob/Test_project/Test_project_service/src

sonar.java.binaries= /home/workspace/codecoveragejob/Test_project/Test_project_service/src
```

Hope that helps...

Comment: I didn't have `sonar.java.binaries` in my properties file, I think that's why I got the error, now it's fixed, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You have unit tests in `argouml-app` that are failing. You can either fix the code or the tests so that they pass. Or you can just skip the tests by running `mvn install -DskipTests` when building the project. This will allow you to build the project and produce the binaries that Sonar needs.

Comment: Skipping the tests helped to resolve the build problem but I still got the error with the binary files which I solved with the help of @Ankur :) thanks anyways